# How run react-app on node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Webpack is manually set without create-react-app.

Can it be used with a webpack dev server?

Which is the easiest way, without express?

Comment: Did you try to lookup at docs? or maybe google around?

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package "serve" on your static build:
In terminal:

```
npm install -g serve // Global npm install
serve [options] <path> // Where option is optional and path is the folder you want to serve
```